# Unable to print the log in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am calling python program in my robot framework and trying to get the output in the console.
I tried a lot but could not solve this issue as i am new to Robot framework.

Issue: Print statement coded in python program is not reflecting in the log console .

My robot file contains the below lines of codes

```
*** Keywords ***
Run App1 Health Check
     [Documentation]    Runs App1 Health check
     ${result} =  Run Process  python  -c ./statuspgm.py app1 timeout=10s
     Log To Console  ${result.stdout}
     [Return]        Pass
```

Program: statuspgm.py

```
import string
import time
…
def RetrievePodsForStatus(pod_srch):
      out_list.append([i.name, i.status])
  print ("Starting the script execution….")
  print("Return value:", ret_val) 
  return out_list

..
# Main Area
arg1 = sys.argv[1]
print ("arg1:", arg1)
component_status = RetrievePodsForStatus(arg1)
print("Out:",component_status)
```

My robot output is:

```
KEYWORD ${result} = Process . Run Process python, -c /home/ubuntu/testpgm.py app1
Documentation:  
Runs a process and waits for it to complete.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20200914 20:01:50.327 / 20200914 20:01:50.356 / 00:00:00.029
20:01:50.327    INFO    Starting process:
python "-c /home/ubuntu/testpgm.py app1"    
20:01:50.332    INFO    Waiting for process to complete.    
20:01:50.356    INFO    Process completed.  
20:01:50.356    INFO    ${result} = <result object with rc 1>   
00:00:00.001KEYWORD BuiltIn . Log To Console ${result.stdout}
Documentation:  
Logs the given message to the console.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20200914 20:01:50.357 / 20200914 20:01:50.358 / 00:00:00.001
20:01:50.358    INFO    ${healthStatus} = Pass
```

Comment: The output you have linked does not seem to be the console log, it is more like the copy of the log.html output. If you want to print the STDOUT there, you should use `Log    ${result.stdout}` instead of `Log to console    ${result.stdout}`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I found -c mentioned in the keyword line that gives the rc code as 1. so i removed "-c" and executed but now facing                           FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python ./testpgm.py app1'                                                               Can anybody tell me how to code in Robotframework to get the current working directory while running the keywords.?    i tried cwd command but getting "No keyword with name 'Log cwd' found."

Comment: I suggest this http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html in general, holds the answer for many questions.
For current directory, read this part: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#built-in-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
${result} =  Run Process  python -c ./statuspgm.py app1 timeout=10s  shell=true
```

There was a double space between "`python`" and "`-c`". So delete one space and set the `shell` argument to `True`.